# What is difference between factory and invocable services in zend2?

Tags: service-locator

Can anyone describe in depth what is difference between factory and invocable services in zend2.
Can invocable service accpet constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

– “invokables” tells to the ServiceManager to instantiate the class when it’s needed.

– “factories” is simillar to the “invokables” but it should be used when you need some additional configuration, as you can see in the examples you mentioned in your question.